# Strange "attempt to perform arithmetic on a function value" error in lua

Tags: lua

I'm writing a BASIC interpreter in plain Lua, have hit a wall when writing my SLEEP X function.

I'm no expert but nothing looks wrong here...

```lua
function s(time)
local time=tonumber(time)
if useSleep then sleep(time) elseif useWait then wait(time) else
--oh no
--we will try our best
local ct=os.time+time
repeat until(os.time>=ct)
end end
--test
s(5)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to call `os.time`, with `os.time()`.

`os.time` is the function.

`os.time()` is its result.